# why Laravel database connection change only for once?

Tags: php, laravel, database, configuration, connection

I have many databases for each user has its database , and I add field in user I called 'company'
have a name of database belong to user , and I change the database connection (I called it 'other' as I define it in .env) when user login , by set config ,

```
config(['database.connections.other.database' => Auth::user()->company]);
```

and it is work fine .
but the problem is I must set the config before any Query .
I add lisener

```
LogSuccessfulLogin
```

and I put the config on it;
and i confirm that it change correct by

```
info(config('database.connections.other.database'));
```

and it is change correct ,
But in any controller after that it return back to the default one in the .env file;

Comment: could you show your use case, like where you are trying to get a different connection? By the way, are you using two database connections and having difficult connecting on second one? Or, its you have the same connection just want to use different database?

Comment: Did you try to add `protected $connection` inside the model ?

Comment: yes Mr. Saroj Shresta .. I have two connection .. the first one for users and auth .. the second for the databases of my customers which are the same structure..  each a group of customers have its own database . and I add  protected $connection for the model who belong to second connection .. I do not have problem to connect with the second when I need by (set config) , but the problem is that I need to only change the when the user login , not every time before any query .

Comment: yes xenooooo , I had do .